# Output from snmpget to bash array

Tags: arrays, string, bash

Trying to get output from snmpget into an array in bash.
The purpose is to query a SAN device for SNMP status.
snmpget commandline is as follows

```
# /usr/bin/snmpget -v2c -Oqv -c public nas.mynetwork.lcl .1.3.6.1.4.1.9804.3.1.1.2.1.30.0 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9804.3.1.1.2.1.39.0
```

And its output is like

```
"P4500G2"
"12 600GB SAS 3.0Gbps drives"
```

I intend to use this in a script so I made variables of the whole command line. Here's the script, sending its output to a new array variable and then looping through the array.

```
# Paths and options
SNMPGET='/usr/bin/snmpget'
SNMPOPTIONS='-v2c -Oqv -c public'
SNMPHOST='nas.mynetwork.lcl'
SNMPOID1='.1.3.6.1.4.1.9804.3.1.1.2.1.30.0'
SNMPOID2='.1.3.6.1.4.1.9804.3.1.1.2.1.39.0'

# Run the command, strip quotes and leave output in variable SNMPREPLY
SNMPREPLY=($($SNMPGET $SNMPOPTIONS $SNMPHOST $SNMPOID1 $SNMPOID2 | tr -d '"'))

# Check what's in the array
for index in ${SNMPREPLY[*]}
 do echo $index
done
```

Output from the above script is this

```
P4500G2
12
600GB
SAS
3.0Gbps
drives
```

As you can see the quotes are properly gone as intended, but every word from the snmpget was put in a separate array item. This is not the purpose but to keep each output line as a separate array item.

Tried to look into the bash IFS variable but can not get it work no matter what.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to read the output line by line and append it to the array, rather than trying to capture it all at once.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    snmpreply+=( "$line" )
done < <($SNMPGET $SNMPOPTIONS $SNMPHOST $SNMPOID1 $SNMPOID2 | tr -d '"')
```

Here, we redirect standard input for the loop (and thus the `read` command) from a process substitution. The output of the command inside the `<(...)` is treated as if it were a file. It's similar to the use of a pipeline

```
snmp ... | while IFS= read -r line; do
   ...
done
```

except it ensures that the loop runs in the current shell, so that the array you build in the loop is still available once the loop exits.

(If you are using `bash` 4, you can replace the loop with the `readarray` command:

```
# -t strips the newlines from each line
readarray -t snmpreply < <( $SNMPGET ... )
```

)

When iterating over the array, use `@` instead of `*` and quote the expansion, to protect whitespace.

```
for item in "${snmpreply[@]}"
 do echo "item"
done
```

---

A few other notes:

1. Don't use all-uppercase names for your variables; those are reserved.

   ```
   snmpget='/usr/bin/snmpget'
   snmpoptions='-v2c -Oqv -c public'
   snmphost='nas.mynetwork.lcl'
   snmpoid1='.1.3.6.1.4.1.9804.3.1.1.2.1.30.0'
   snmpoid2='.1.3.6.1.4.1.9804.3.1.1.2.1.39.0'
   ```
2. Use an array to store multiple options for a command. You can store all the arguments in the same array for ease of calling:

   ```
   snmpoptions=( -v2c -0qv -c public   # your original options
                 nas.mynetwork.lcl     # the host
                 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9804.3.1.1.2.1.30.0  # oid1
                 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9804.3.1.1.2.1.39.0  # oid2
                 )
   ```

   When calling the command, quote all parameter expansions:

   ```
   "$snmpget" "${snpoptions[@]}"
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.
I do not fully understand the first code block and why it works. But will look into it and try to understand. At a quick glance I think it is reading the $SNMPGET output line-by-line and appending it to the snmpreply variable. Nice.

Comment: I'll expand on the use of the process substitution syntax (`<(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

IFS is the right way to go.

```
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
f() { echo "'P4500G2'"; echo "'12 600GB SAS 3.0Gbps drives'"; }
f
'P4500G2'
'12 600GB SAS 3.0Gbps drives'

a=($(f))
for i in ${a[*]}; do echo $i ; done
'P4500G2'
'12 600GB SAS 3.0Gbps drives'

IFS=$OIFS
for i in ${a[*]}; do echo $i ; done
'P4500G2'
'12
600GB
SAS
3.0Gbps
drives'
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand where in my little script I should put it. If inserting it immediately before the command SNMPREPLY= .... the command fails with "Invalid version specified after -v flag: 2c -Oqv -c public"

Comment: Indeed, it should be put before looping over the array.